# Is TFS 2010 license required?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msdn

We are currently using Visual Studio 2010 Premium with TFS 2010. Every developer that uses VS 2010 has a MSDN license.

Our DBA also wants to utilize TFS 2010, but using Visual Studio 2008 BI Development Studio. The DBA doesn’t have a VS 2010 MSDN license. The solution I have found is to install:

1. Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer (VS2008TeamExplorer.iso)
2. Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (VS2008SP1ENUX1512962.iso)
3. VS90SP1-KB974558-x86.exe

I am able to connect to our TFS 2010.

But, my question is: Does our DBA require a msdn license in order to connect to TFS 2010? If yes, how much would it cost per DBA (roughly)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An MSDN license is overkill in this case. Your DBA just needs to have a TFS Client Access License (CAL) which you should be able to acquire through your MS rep or software reseller of choice.

Comment: The TFS 2010 CAL regular price is $499 but you can get it for $431.99 at amazon as of 7/19/2011.